# unable to locate spring namespacehandler for xml schema namespace context

Tags: java, spring

I got an error "unable to locate spring namespacehandler for xml schema namespace context" after running the jar file.

java -jar someJar.jar

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

I could see same url pasted twice  :- http://www.springframework.org/schema/context, However below definition hopefully work for you as we need to provide the schemalocation which seems missed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
```